# Looking for help with installer on English(US) Windows

Tags: .net, wpf

Could someone, who has English(US) Windows try to install and run my program, please? The program uses WPF and requires .NET Framework 4.0, and this framework should be installed automatically during the installation of the program.

Unfortunately it looks like something is bad with the setup file or with the program, because nobody from the U.S. run my program up this time (I see how the program asks for an update on my server during each start of the program - there are a lot of requests worldwide but none of them is from the U.S.).

I can't try it my self, because I don't have English(US) Windows and on my Windows program runs perfeclty. I know that this is not a typical question about programming, but I don't know where else to find help.

Official site of the program is here: http://en-us.1-easysoft.com/SK_ABC/index.html

Thanks for any help.

Tomas

Comment: Do you really think people will install some unknown software from an unknown source on their machines?

Answer (score 7):

You should install a virtual machine or a physical machine with the required OS so that you can test this yourself.

Answer (score 3):

As a more general solution to this problem, have you considered utilising the [Internet Explorer VPC images](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=21EABB90-958F-4B64-B5F1-73D0A413C8EF&displaylang=en)? They're a good way to get hold of "ready to run" images of Windows that, I believe, are configured for a US locale (This has the benefit of meaning that you don't have to *pay* for a copy of English Windows to use for testing).

Given that they're virtual images you have the added advantage of being able to wipe-clean and start again fairly quickly, something that's **essential** when testing and developing setup software.

Answer (score 1):

Download a trial windows kit from Microsoft and install it under [Virtual PC](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/) in order to test you app.